# Spring RSocket high CPU usage after client disconnect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java

I've created a simple RSocket endpoint with Spring RSocket support:

```
@Controller
class SampleController {

    @MessageMapping("sample")
    fun sample(): Flux<ByteArray> {
        return Flux
            .fromIterable(generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }.asIterable())
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
            .doOnNext { println(it) }
            .map { it.toString().toByteArray() }
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as a client is connected and pulling data:

`rsc tcp://localhost:8888 --stream --route sample`

Once I cancel this, CPU usage gets to 20%. If I run more `rsc` clients in parallel, CPU usage will be >50% when I cancel all of them.

I was trying to look for some samples where there is a clean-up on the server side, but didn't manage to find anything. Also, I've enabled global DEBUG logging level (`logging.level.root=DEBUG`), but there are is nothing in the logs after clients are canceled. I was thinking maybe there's some sort of automatic reconnection mechanism that kicks in and starts spamming requests.

So, am I missing something, and is there a way such behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or known bug, can you look at the RSocket-Java issue tracker please, and if nothing similar report this as a bug providing more details on rsocket-java version, your setup, and required details to help us identify the problem. Thanks

Comment: Any chance you have a resumable server and you are collecting results in the meantime?

Comment: @YuriSchimke Server is constantly running and accepting new requests. Collection of results, on the other hand, is stopped when client is stopped. I'm logging things on server side and there're no logs once client disconnects. Also, I can have 100 clients connected and CPU usage is minimal, but the problem happens when I start canceling them

Comment: Capture some stacktaces so you can see what is happening.

Comment: @OlehDokuka As you suggested, I went through issues list on Github and didn't find anything that looks like this. Therefore, I've opened a new one: https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/issues/992 I hope it helps understand the issue a bit better (even if it's something that I've missed)

Comment: Have seen it. thanks